# ¿ Por qué no funciona este sencillo código de listView?

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente codigo para un listview (layout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_principal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#489e37" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_secundario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Donde tengo dos textview para cada item de la lista, el .java es :

```
public class LenguajeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final Integer[] integers;

    public LenguajeListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] integers) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_profesorado, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.integers=integers;
    }

    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profesorado,null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.texto_principal);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView etxDescripcion = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.texto_secundario);

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[posicion]);
        imageView.setImageResource(integers[posicion]);

        etxDescripcion.setText("primero "+itemname[0]);
        etxDescripcion.setText("segundo "+itemname[1]);
        etxDescripcion.setText("tercero "+itemname[2]);
        etxDescripcion.setText("cuarto "+itemname[3]);
        etxDescripcion.setText("quinto "+itemname[4]);
        etxDescripcion.setText("sexto "+itemname[5]);

        return rowView;
    }
```

Esos `etxDescripcion.setText` es para poner en el TextView secundario un texto, estoy poniendo en qué posición quiero que vayan con los números en `itemname[x]` pero me salen todos el mismo o me sale error a veces, ¿No es así para poner un texto en cada posición distinta?

El `.Main` es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String lenguajeProgramacion[]=new String[]{"Java","PHP","Python","JavaScript","Ruby","C",
            "Go","Perl","Pascal"};

    private Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.java,
            R.drawable.php,
            R.drawable.python,
            R.drawable.javascript,
            R.drawable.ruby,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.go,
            R.drawable.perl,
            R.drawable.pascal
    };

    private ListView lista;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LenguajeListAdapter adapter=new LenguajeListAdapter(this,lenguajeProgramacion,imgid);
        lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mi_lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String Slecteditem= lenguajeProgramacion[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No funciona a que te refieres, no se despliega o tienes un error que cierra tu app,???

Comment: Lo siento, no funciona es que todos los textos secundarios de cada item me salen con "sexto" es decir, con el ultimo que pongo. Yo pensaba que así lograba que cada item tuviera su texto secundario pero no... ¿ sabes como ? Sé que es una instrucción porque me suena pero no la encuentro..

Comment: @RfMvs Ya hiciste más de 20 preguntas. ¿No crees que ya es hora de saber cómo darle formato al código, **aceptar** alguna respuesta haciendo click en el **✓**, o votar a favor de alguna? Te invito a leer [tour]

Comment: No sabia que habia que darle click, lo siento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que deberías implementar el método `getCount()` y establecer ahí el tamaño de tu array. El `getView()` utiliza automáticamente ese dato del `getCount` para saber cuantas veces el `getView` tiene que ser llamado. En otras palabras, el `getView` es invocado el número de veces que contiene el `getCount`.

Intenta sólo incluir una de estas lineas en el `getView` después de implementar el `getCount`

```
etxDescripcion.setText("primero "+itemname[posicion]);
```

Ahora para los argumentos del `setText("primero", "segundo", etc..)` tendrías que crear otro array para se generen ese textos.

La razón por la cual te aparece "sexto" es porque esta última línea de código opaca a las 5 anteriores, es decir es como si no existieran. Solo tiene que haber una linea de estas:

```
etxDescripcion.setText(...);
```